# graphiql interface shows no results, but query returns valid response

Tags: aws-amplify, graphiql

I googled a bit, but couldn't find anyone else complaining about this issue. I am using `amplify mock` to test GraphQL queries locally. Everything works as expected, mutations do insert data to Sqlite DB just fine, however query results do not show in GraphiQL UI. I checked the browser developer tools console for any errors, but none shown. The HTTP response does show the expected results. Tried in Chrome and Safari only to see same behavior. I am on MacOS Monterey. Any tips appreciated.

```
query MyQuery {
  getBlog(id: "73545774-56dd-45d9-b34c-ada280cc7ef4") {
    id
    name
    updatedAt
    createdAt
  }
}
```

The ID shown in the query above is a record that exists in Sqlite DB. it was inserted through a Mutation query. The browser tab does show the below correct response.

```json
{
    "data": {
        "getBlog": {
            "id": "73545774-56dd-45d9-b34c-ada280cc7ef4",
            "name": "First Blog",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-27T17:55:02.052Z",
            "createdAt": "2022-07-27T17:55:02.052Z"
        }
    }
}
```

However, the GraphiQL interface not render the results correctly. It does show some expand/collapse arrow icons. See attached screenshot:

[Results pane in GraphiQL shows empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryTAw.png)

Why would GraphiQL interface behave this way? Any suggestions?

This is my setup:

```
node -v
v16.13.0

npm -v
8.5.2

amplify -v
9.1.0

Google Chrome
103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (x86_64)
```

```
npm create-react-app myapp
cd myapp
npm install @aws-amplify/cli -g
amplify init
amplify add api

DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT='http://localhost:62224' amplify mock
...

AppSync Mock endpoint is running at http://10.0.0.180:20002
```

Comment: same issue for me with amplify-cli v9.1.0